# Laravel mysql query to get ranking of teams by checking total points

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need a query which can give me a list of top 2 teams by using total points they have, in short like a leaderboard, if any team has the same points on rank 2, both team data should be returns

For the testing you can use below records

id - 1,
name - ABC,
total_points - 250

id - 2,
name - DEF,
total_points - 120

id - 3,
name - PQR,
total_points - 120

id - 4,
name - MNO,
total_points - 20

These should return below records

id - 1,
name - ABC,
total_points - 250,
rank - 1

id - 2,
name - DEF,
total_points - 120,
rank - 2

id - 3,
name - PQR,
total_points - 120,
rank - 2

Comment: And what query have you tried ?

Comment: @Lk77
I tried with limit, offset and max but not suitable

Comment: limit() and orderByDesc() is what you need, you don't need anything else

Comment: @Lk77 what if having same points on any rank?

Comment: Well it does not matter, it will take the first 3 anyway, because there is a limit. There is the edge case of having more than 3 teams with the same score but is it something you want to handle ?

Comment: But, i want top 3 means if having 10 teams covered in top 3, i should have list of all 10 teams
limit will limit to 3

Comment: You can also make two queries, one: recover the winning scores, and 2 recover the teams : ```$winningResults = Result::select('total_points')->orderByDesc('total_points')->limit(3)->get()``` and ```Result::whereIn('total_points', $winningResults->map->total_points)->get()``` it will return all teams that have a winning score. If 4 teams have scored 120 and the other 6 have scored 100, it will return only the 4 teams with a score of 120

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.